# MYSql Trigger not making any changes to db

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a SQL statement that doesn't appear to want to run as a trigger, it allowed it to be stored as a trigger but it doesn't make any changes, its been added to the DB with phpmyadmin on table 'ebaylinked' to fire after update

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Update` AFTER UPDATE ON `ebaylinked`
 FOR EACH ROW UPDATE product
INNER JOIN ebaylinked e ON ebaylinked.ebay_ID = product.eBay_ID
SET product.product_stock =product.product_stock - ebaylinked.QuantitySold, 
ebaylinked.Processed=0
WHERE
ebaylinked.Processed = 1
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: make sure you've connected your connection file

Comment: I would recommend if you're having trouble with triggers that you post the trigger creation statement.

Comment: has been updated thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have the `inner join` but could you try the following, this should update product_stock and processed in your product table where product's id = the product's id that was updated:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Update` AFTER UPDATE ON `ebaylinked`
 FOR EACH ROW UPDATE product

SET product.product_stock =product.product_stock - ebaylinked.QuantitySold, 
ebaylinked.Processed=0
WHERE
ebaylinked.Processed = 1 and product.eBay_ID = new.eBay_ID
```

Comment: Is valid and adds to database but doesn't do anything =S